# UITextField "value changed" not firing when field is updated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have an `IBAction` that I have connected to a `UITextField` element in Interface Builder. (Firing on "value changed" event)

I also have a `UISlider` that updates the TextField element automatically when it's value gets adjusted.

When I run my app, the TextField does get updated when I adjust the slider, but the "value changed" event does not fire when this happens. The value changed event also does not fire when I edit the TextField by hand as well. (Although using the Did Editing End trigger does cause it to fire).

My question is, how can I get the value changed trigger to fire for both a programmatic update of the TextField as well as when the user adjusts the value.

Comment: Hi, why you didn't use UITextFieldDelegate methods ?

Comment: They serve different purposes. `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` allows you to decide whether change should happen or not, and you need to calculate what the result would be yourself. So if the change is always going to happen, and you only care about what the changed value is, using `UIControlEventEditingChanged` is definitely easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by TheRonin, use `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the following method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Comment: Do I implement this inside of my view controller?

Comment: Yes. Add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in .h file interface declaration. Set the textfield's delegate to file owner through nib file. Implement the above said method inside viewcontroller.

Comment: Does this also work when the textfield is updated programmatically?

Comment: Wouldn't this one be more logical to use? `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` , however I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this delegate method, can you include the implementation in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it is called _before_ the typed character is committed. That is, if you've type `fo` and then type `o`, the `textField.text` is still `fo` and not yet `foo`. You'd have to apply the change manually to get the string the textfield will be set to.

Comment: This is not the right method. UITextField delegate asks you to return a BOOL not to manipulate your state in some way. Mark Adams answer is the right one and the one I was searching for.

Comment: I second @DarkDust and Gabriele. Implement textFieldDidEndEditing instead.

Comment: This really is not the correct answer.  MarkAdams answer is correct.

Comment: and? it is called when text is not changed yet and you should recalculate the result string if you plan to use it

Answer (score 246):

Don't use `UIControlEventValueChanged` for `UITextField`. What you want is `UIControlEventEditingChanged`.

Comment: I'm not arguing that if works or not, but I would just like to know why this is the case?

Comment: I tried that one and it doesn't fire when the textfield is programmatically changed.

Comment: Correct, none of the target/action events are invoked for programmatic changes by design.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `UITextFieldDelegate` does totally different thing.

Answer (score 76):

To get `EditingChanged  textfield event`, I suggested add selector as

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

As textfield value changed, the changed value you will get from this `textChanged:` selector.

```
-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textfield data %@ ",textField.text);
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution and fires exactly when you'd expect!

Comment: I am wondering why they have value changed event for if its not working

Answer (score 12):

IF you are assigning a delegate to the text field then note that  (when you return NO from the delegate method below, the event (Editing changed) won't be triggered. Consider invoking the event listener when you do return NO from this method

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Comment: The Editing Changed event will not be triggered because the field *did not change* -- that's what returning NO does!

Comment: @olie - But sometimes you change the field programmatically in that delegate method and then return NO to override the user's default text. This was my case and this answer solved the problem.

Comment: Sure, but that's not an *editing* change.  If you want to do that, your code should also call the changed selector on the delegate.  That way, you're in full control.

Answer (score 4):

While value gets assigned programmatically, in that case, textFieldDidChange never get called because actually textField hasn't changed. For this external event needs to pass

eg., **textfield.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)** this will fire the editing changed event and textFieldDidChange will get called even after value changed programmatically.

> *Where to apply this event*:

After assigning value to the text filed eg., **textfield.text = "some value"**

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but the first search result I found, and none of the answers are satisfactory.  I found this solution to work best: [Swift UITextField subclass handle text change programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094710/swift-uitextfield-subclass-handle-text-change-programmatically).

Override UITextField's text property to add a didSet(), and call your value changed function from there.

```
  override open var text: String? {
        didSet {
            myValueDidChange()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!

    // MARK: View lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleTextField.delegate = self
    }
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate methods
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("changed")
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For **Swift 3**:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .valueChanged)

func textChanged() { 
 .... 
}
```

Comment: when you want to get input while editing, you need to use `for: .editingChanged`.

Comment: @ChangnamHong nope its not work now, you should use `.valueChanged`