# Swift UITextField subclass handle text change programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have a subclass of `UITextField` that is specific to handle Date text. I have a `tableviewcell` that uses this text field:

```
let dateInput: DateTextField
```

Now the controller needs to initialize the text of the `dateInput` prior to display as follows:

```
cell.dateInput.text = "01/29/2016"
```

Now, I want to be able to detect that the text changed from the subclass so that I can update the internal date variable so that is it in-sync with the text.

I implemented the textfield delegate methods but that just catches changes made by the user and not programmatically.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand what you're trying to do... Can you elaborate a little bit or make it clearer?

Comment: I have a subclass of UItextField that displays only Date strings. A Controller is setting the text programmatically (dateTextField.text="01/12/2015"). So I am trying to figure out how to catch that the text has changed so that I can update some backend variables in the DateTextField class. Does this explain better?

Comment: since we are talking strings here, why not just do if condition where (dateInput.text == "01/29/2016")...? This can be done in an initial method such as viewWillAppear and based on that do asynchronous call to backend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override property and add `didSet` observer in your custom class:

```
class DateTextField: UITextField {

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
           // Do your stuff here    
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Internal iOS routines do not use the "text" nor "attributedText" properties, they are just for external use. For example, when the user is typing on your text field, the internal events are the only way to get the textField values, because UIKit is changing the internal variable only, not the "text" or "attributedText" properties.

Comment: This works perfectly if you're setting your text somewhere (`textField.text = "some text"`) and you want the `UITextField` subclass to respond after that.

Answer (score 5):

My solution for this is to have each instance of the subclass maintain its own notification for `UITextFieldDidChange` and use a custom protocol to relay that information to the listener.

```
protocol MutableTextFieldDelegate {
    func textChanged(_ sender:MutableTextField)
}

class MutableTextField : UITextField {

    var textChangedDelegate : MutableTextFieldDelegate?

    var previousValue : String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: self, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            guard let object = notification.object as? MutableTextField, object == strongSelf else { return }

            if strongSelf.previousValue != strongSelf.text {
                strongSelf.textChangedDelegate?.textChanged(strongSelf)
            }
            strongSelf.previousValue = strongSelf.text
        }
    }
}
```

swift5: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification` ...

Comment: Don’t forget to remove the observer on `deinit()` here, otherwise these observers will linger forever

Comment: This is no longer true. "As of iOS 9 (and OS X 10.11), you don't need to remove observers yourself, if you're not using block based observers though. The system will do it for you, since it uses zeroing-weak references for observers, where it can." https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339926/916299

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I noted it as they are actually using a closure here

Comment: The example above uses block-based observer, so it needs to be removed afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Check the UIControlEventEditingChanged event...within it, you can set following logic.

Example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event) post:

```
// Add a "textFieldDidChange" notification method to the text field control.
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but textFieldDidChange is not being called in iOS9 when setting the text (dateTextField.text = "12/01/2015").